# expandCapacity method in AbstractStringBuilder class

Tags: java

I was looking through the source code of this class and I start from append method that is called by `StringBUffer.append();`

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
   if (str == null) str = "null";
       int len = str.length();
   if (len == 0) return this;
   int newCount = count + len;
   if (newCount > value.length)
      expandCapacity(newCount); // newcount is the new volumn of a char array
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count = newCount;
    return this;
  }
```

Then I went deeper into `enpandCapacity` method

```
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2; //here value is a char array 
    if (newCapacity < 0) { // Why is newCapacity less than 0?
                           // Is that possible? When it will be possible?
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else if (minimumCapacity > newCapacity) {
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

Why is `newCapacity` less than 0? Is that possible? When it will be possible?

Comment: It's called arithmetic overflow. Signed integers in Java overflow such that `MAX_VALUE + 1 == MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Take for example `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2`, which evaluates to `-2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; signed integers can become negative once the max value of the int type (*2^31 - 1*) is exceeded. If you take a look, they are essentially capping the capacity at `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Similar type of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270788/whats-causing-java-hailstone-sequence-to-crash-in-my-program/12270870#12270870).